# Spring Oauth2 integrattion of two authorization servers into one resource server app

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I need to integrate two different oauth2 authorization servers into a resource server spring app.
My resource server must try to validate the access token against the first authorization server, and if not successful, against the second one.
As the validation happens in different ways, I need to have different tokenServices and tokenStores. What I dont understand is which bean of Spring allows me to do this, acting before the call of loadAuthentication.